# Remove for loop from stringdist algorithm in R

Tags: r, for-loop, stringdist

I've made an algorithm to determine scores of matching strings from 2 dataframes in R. It will search for each row in test_ech the matching rows which their score is above 0.75 in test_data (based on the matching of 3 columns from each data frame).

Well, my code works perfectly with small data frame but I'm dealing with dataframes of 12m rows and the process will take at least 5 days to be done. So I think that if I discard "for loops" It will work but I really don't know how to do it. (and if there's extra changes that I need to do to lighten the process)

Thanks.

```r
#score function :

library(stringdist)

score <- function(i,j) 
{  
s_n<-stringsim(test_ech[j,3],test_data[i,5],method = "jw",p=0.15)
s_v<-stringsim(test_ech[j,5],test_data[i,4],method = "jw",p=0.15)
s_c<-stringsim(test_ech[j,4],test_data[i,3],method = "jw",p=0.15)

 return(s_n*0.6+s_v*0.25+s_c*0.15)
}

#initialize result data frame :

resultat<-data.frame(nom_AS400=character(),ville_AS400=character(),cp_AS400=character(),                nom_SIRENE=character(),ville_SIRENE=character(),cp_SIRENE=character(),score=double())

#algo textmining :

system.time(for (j in 1:nrow(test_ech)) {

  for (i in 1:nrow(test_data)) {

    x<-score(i,j)

    if (x>0.75) {

ligne<-data.frame(nom_AS400=test_ech[j,3],
       ville_AS400=test_ech[j,5],
       cp_AS400=test_ech[j,4],
       nom_SIRENE=test_data[i,5],
       ville_SIRENE=test_data[i,4],
       cp_SIRENE=test_data[i,3],
       score=x)

      resultat<-rbind(resultat,ligne)      
    }  
  } 
})
```

test_ech : 65k rows and test_data : 12m rows

```r
#test_ech (5 rows)
structure(list(societe_code = c("01", "01", "01", "01", "01"), 
    client_code = c("00048I", "00059Z", "00070Q", "00080W", "00131L"
    ), client_lib = c("CFA VAUBAN", "ALLRIM SA", "ATS CULLIGAN", 
    "AHSSEA", "ETS BRUNEAU P"), client_cp = c("25001", "25401", 
    "25480", "70002", "94700"), client_ville = c("BESANCON CEDEX", 
    "AUDINCOURT CEDEX", "ECOLE VALENTIN", "VESOUL CEDEX", "MAISONS ALFORT"
    )))

#test_data (5 rows)
structure(list(siren = c("005450093", "005450095", "005541552", 
"005580501", "005620117"), siret = c("00545009300033", "00545009300041", 
"00554155200039", "00558050100012", "00562011700019"), codePostalEtablissement = c("04800", 
"04802", "04260", "44600", "80100"), libelleCommuneEtablissement = c("GREOUX LES BAINS", 
"BAINS", "ALLOS", "SAINT NAZAIRE", "ABBEVILLE"), ref = c("PASSIONNEMENT GLAMOUR", 
"GLAMOUR", "LE SYMPA SNACK", "STEF", "DUBOIS")))
```

the expected output is a dataframe with the 3 reference columns from test_ech with the 3 matching columns from test_data and the score which should be >0.75

[output link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzTVN.png)

Comment: Hi Amine, can you give us a sample of your data base using the dput() function?

Comment: I'm afraid, you have to call `score` 12m·12m times, which is 1,4·10^14, which is a lot. No matter if you are using for loops or arrays…

Comment: You can run it in parallel, with a nice computer look into the future package

Comment: @ziggystar I updated the post at the end...test_ech : 65k rows and test_data : 12m rows... So yes you have to call score 12m times for 65k rows in total

Comment: @Luis I've updated the post you can find the 2 data frames using the dput() function

Comment: Please double check your example data from `dput` it appears incomplete. And if you can make sure that some entries meet your score threshold.

Comment: @Amine96, I'm unable to make your example work. After running do.call(cbind.data.frame, test_ech) to turn your dput object from a list to a dataframe (same for test_data), I run score(1, 1) and it doesn't work. The function itself is calling for the fourth and fifth column of test_ech and test_data, but the dput objects only have 3 columns

Comment: @emilliman5  dput code updated (sorry for the delay)

Comment: @Luis dput code updated (sorry for the delay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this completely solves your problem given the dimensions of your original data, but you can reduce your time substantially by doing it over one `for` loop instead of two. You can do this because the `stringsim` function accepts a single character object on one side and a vector on the other.

```
    score_2 <- function(j) 
{  
  s_n <- stringsim(test_ech[[j,3]], test_data[[5]], method = "jw", p = 0.15)
  s_v <- stringsim(test_ech[[j,5]], test_data[[4]], method = "jw", p = 0.15)
  s_c <- stringsim(test_ech[[j,4]], test_data[[3]], method = "jw", p = 0.15)

  return(s_n * 0.6 + s_v * 0.25 + s_c * 0.15)
}

    stringsim (test_ech[,3], test_data[,5])

    resultat<-data.frame(nom_AS400=character(),ville_AS400=character(),cp_AS400=character(),                nom_SIRENE=character(),ville_SIRENE=character(),cp_SIRENE=character(),score=double())

    for (j in 1:nrow(test_ech)) {

      x <- score_2(j)

      x_75 = which(x > 0.75)

      if(length(x_75) > 0){
        for(i in x_75){

         ligne<-data.frame(nom_AS400=test_ech[[j,3]],
                           ville_AS400=test_ech[[j,5]],
                           cp_AS400=test_ech[[j,4]],
                           nom_SIRENE=test_data[[i,5]],
                           ville_SIRENE=test_data[[i,4]],
                           cp_SIRENE = test_data[[i,3]],                       
                           score = x[i])

      resultat<-rbind(resultat,ligne)

    }
   }
  }
```

Your function, repeating both your test objects 60 times:

```
  usuário   sistema decorrido 
     9.59      1.43     11.12
```

This function, repeating both test objects 60 times:

```
  usuário   sistema decorrido 
     0.21      0.08      0.18
```

Quite a bit faster :)

(note: there is `stringdistmatrix` which accepts vectors on both sides and returns a matrix, but sadly there is no `stringsimmatrix`. If you can map out the difference between `stringdist` and `stringsim`, running `stringdistmatrix` and adjusting it would probably be even faster).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I like the use of only one loop instead of two. Yet, there's an issue with the score function, it will calculate the score matching of one string from test_ech[,3] with a vector containing all strings in test_data[,5], and in the end it will return the MEAN value of the score when matching all strings in test_data and not each score for each matching.

Comment: I've updated your code in an answer post... Many thanks for your help

Comment: @Amine96 Ah, you're right, it should have been x[i] instead of x[x_75]. Anyway, at least your problem is solved. Do you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: No worries, yet you need to update your code with mine to mark it as an answer.(I also changed the score function with [[]] in test_data and test_ech)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've solved the problem thanks to @Luis with using only one loop instead of two.

Code below :

```r
    score_2 <- function(j) 
{  
  s_n <- stringsim(test_ech[[j,3]], test_data[[5]], method = "jw", p = 0.15)
  s_v <- stringsim(test_ech[[j,5]], test_data[[4]], method = "jw", p = 0.15)
  s_c <- stringsim(test_ech[[j,4]], test_data[[3]], method = "jw", p = 0.15)

  return(s_n * 0.6 + s_v * 0.25 + s_c * 0.15)
}

    stringsim (test_ech[,3], test_data[,5])

    resultat<-data.frame(nom_AS400=character(),ville_AS400=character(),cp_AS400=character(),                nom_SIRENE=character(),ville_SIRENE=character(),cp_SIRENE=character(),score=double())

    for (j in 1:nrow(test_ech)) {

      x <- score_2(j)

      x_75 = which(x > 0.75)

      if(length(x_75) > 0){
        for(i in x_75){

         ligne<-data.frame(nom_AS400=test_ech[[j,3]],
                           ville_AS400=test_ech[[j,5]],
                           cp_AS400=test_ech[[j,4]],
                           nom_SIRENE=test_data[[i,5]],
                           ville_SIRENE=test_data[[i,4]],
                           cp_SIRENE = test_data[[i,3]],                       
                           score = x[i])

      resultat<-rbind(resultat,ligne)

    }
   }
  }
```